# How to auto-complete main() in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse Helios. I am wondering if there is anyway to add the `main()` method quickly in Eclipse?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Type

```
main
```

then your content assist shortcut key.

[image]

---

> You can also add a main method from the class creation wizard. There's a checkbox to have it put in a main method for you. – [rfreak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557500/rfeak)

Comment: Commenting instead of answering so Matt get's credit. You can also add a main method from the class creation wizard. There's a checkbox to have it put in a main method for you.

Comment: typing just 'm' is enough.

Answer (score 5):

This is just main and <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd>.

Or

type ma and then press <kbd>ctrl+space</kbd>

Or

type m and then press <kbd>ctrl+space</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

There are two easy way to add main method in your class.
1. While creating class there is an option - public static void main(String[] args) option - select the check box.

[image]

2. After creating class also you can add main method. type main and press ctrl+space - the [main - main method] option will be displaying - select it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse you can first type "main" then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> and it can be finished automatically.

And In windows Eclipse, you can type "main" , and then <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> ,it will be finished automatically!

Comment: Only if `ctrl+/` is the content assist shortcut... which for me, it isn't — that includes Eclipse in OS X, Windows, _and_ Linux.

Comment: Currently the default "Content Assist" setting for Eclipse Juno is: `Ctrl`+`space`.
You can find your setting by looking at Eclipse->Window->Preferences->General->Keys

Answer (score 0):

I am on mac and I use TextExpander to create snippets of frequently used codes. I know I am going bit off your question but I am sure this will be very helpful.

You can create snippets of code and assign them keywords. This works with any programming language and in any editor. You just need to type the keyword and your snippet will be auto loaded.

For eg. for my main method I have created keyword *jmain*. So everytime I need main method I just need to type *jmain* and the code will be loaded. You can also control the placement of cursor.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @Aprendiz I have moved on to using Linux as my base dev machine. I haven't used text-expander for a while. So the answer is I don't know :)